# How do I make openldap's client (libldap) accept more than 1024 file descriptors?

Tags: linux, select, openldap, file-descriptor, epoll

OpenLDAP as a server can handle N number of requests because it supports epoll (there is no hard limit). However, when openldap behaves as a client (and tries to communicate with directory services to fulfill client requests), it encounters a problem. As it still uses select(), it cannot accept file descriptors greater than 1024. It's for the Linux operating system. In other words, epoll is used on the server side, while select() is used on the client side. LibLdap could fail to process requests and wonder why select() is still used.

The goal is to make libldap handle more than 1024 Fds. Is it possible to use epoll for libldap as well? Please let me know if you have any better solutions.

It would be great if someone can share their thoughts in this aspect.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have realized that libldap already having a solution in the form of poll(). Earlier I have overlooked taht.